# Why are ES2015 Modules taking so long to be released?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

[Kangax](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) doesn't even mention them. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) is upfront that they're not coming out any time soon. Every other feature of ES2015 has at least partial support.

But at the time of writing, [ES2015 Modules](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-imports) (import/export) are way behind every other feature, yet they have the potential to be the most useful.

Why? Anyone have insight as to the slowness?

Comment: There are many long discussions about how to fit ES6 modules into node.js.  There are serious design complications for how to support them going forward, make them simple and easy to use and the default behavior for the future, but not break the existing module system in any way.  It is a complex topic involving some tradeoffs.  For node.js it is being worked on.

Comment: They are released. They just are not yet supported on all platforms.

Comment: http://es2015-node.js.org/#the-issue

Comment: Are you talking about Node? Browsers? Any other environment? A question like this seems off-topic.

Comment: I think it's a great question as evidenced by the upvotes. I looked for other communities. Couldn't find a better fit. it has to do with development and stackoverflow === development. I didn't specify Node/Browser/environment because they're *ALL* lagging. The accepted answer would apply to all.

Comment: @Bergi Yes sir. The ECMA specs are official, I agree. But a feature isn't released until it can be used. At the time of this writing it is present in zero browsers/servers AFAIK. My question has to do with why it's not *implemented*.

Comment: @Rap [MS Edge supports modules](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2016/05/17/es6-modules-and-beyond) for about a year now. Also, the [spec for loading modules on web sites](https://github.com/whatwg/loader) is not yet finished

Comment: @Bergi I guess if you consider a feature implemented when it is hidden behind an *experimental* flag in one browser then you are correct. I don't consider that implemented. But whatever. The other features in ES2015 are implemented in all browsers without hiding. Without picking more nits, my question is "Why not?" Can we please just focus on that?